# Applying a phone number format mask in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have phone number field in database.
I want to change my phone number format to "XXX-XXX-XXXX" as I type not after the result is submitted

Answer (score 0):

just keep in mind that, in the end, your APEX page is pretty much an HTML document. That said, you're able to tweak it using any JavaScript or CSS you want to.

For input masks, my "go-to" option is: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

I've tried a lot of JS library to mask inputs and that one was the best for my projects.

If you're unsure how to use it, here you go:

1. Import the main [dist file](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/4.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js) to your app. Use can upload it to the workspace, app, it doesn't matter as long you're able to reference it in your page.
2. In your Pn_PHONE page item, go to **Custom Attributes** and enter your mask, for i.e., `data-inputmask="'mask': '999-999-9999'"`
3. In **Execute when Page Loads** enter this code: `$(':input').inputmask();` to apply mask to all inputs with `data-inputmask`.
4. You're done.

Have a look at the JS library [usage](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#usage) to check all settings you can use.

Comment: Hi Rafael thanks for the reply but I cannot find a way to download the "main dist file" to import it in my application.

Comment: You could click on the "Raw" button and then right-click on the page to "Save as..." or you can download the repo here https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/archive/4.x.zip and get the file from the dist folder. Getting the file should be the easiest part ;-)

Comment: Probably not following all the steps mentioned here... Make a simple app on apex.oracle.com with these step-by-step and let me know the app ID / URL. Then I'll be able to point out what is missing.

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4000:1:105313339905577::NO:RP:FB_FLOW_ID,F4000_P1_FLOW:75373,75373                                  username:rawlemusgrave4@hotmail.com     pwd:test

Comment: hi dear  how i can apply that i can't find any steps , please can any one provide me the steps to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In custom attributes you could add:

```
onfocusout="this.value=(this.value).replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3')"
```

This will format the number when you click out of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to implement the formatting as the user was typing and here is the solution which worked for me.

1. On your phone number page item add the dynamic action (DA) for name I put formatPhoneNo, EVENT - KEY RELEASE; SELECTION TYPE - ITEM; ITEM(S) - P1_PHONE_NUMBER. For the True action put 'Execute JavaScript Code' in the Code put:

   phoneNumberAutoFormat (this.triggeringElement);
2. Go to Function and Global Variable Declaration and define

   phoneNumberAutoFormat () function.
   function phoneNumberAutoFormat (phoneNumber)  {
   var res;
   var number = phoneNumber.value.trim().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
   if (number.length < 4) {
   res = number;
   }
   else if ( number.length >= 4 && number.length < 7) {
   res =  String(number).replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1})/, "$1-$2");
   }
   else if  (number.length >= 7 &&  number.length <= 10) {
   res =String(number).replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})/, "$1-$2-$3");
   } else {
   res = String(number).replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
   apex.message.showErrors([{
   type: "error",
   location:   [ "page", "inline" ],
   pageItem:   "P410_PHONE_NUMBER",
   message: "Please enter a valid number. Ex. 555-555-5555",
   unsafe: false
   }]);
   };

   ```
    apex.item('P410_PHONE_NUMBER').setValue(res);
   ```

   }

Please comment any tips on improving this code.

You may also want to include apex.message.clearErrors(); to prevent a pile up of error messages