# How does the format mask work in Oracle APEX?

Tags: database, forms, validation, oracle-apex, input-mask

I have just been given an assignment for University on databases where I have to use Oracle APEX. For one of my columns in a report, I need to use a format mask. The format mask I need in the form of `AAAA00`, where **A** is any letter and **0** is any number.

Trying to get this to work is an issue though. I've heard the syntax for any number is **9** and I assume it's **A** for the letter, so wouldn't the format mask be `AAAA99`?

[This is what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oab3s.png)

I tried using it but didn't succeed. When using the form, you can still input anything. I even tried using one of the default date options for the format mask, and that didn't work either.

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Oracle APEX Format Mask](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) is only for the `Number` and `Date` type objects, you can't format strings using it.

Also, Format Masks are for display only, lets say I have a mask `9G9G9G9` in an Interactive Grid column, it would display numbers like : `3,1,4,1`. I could go and edit my cell putting `1337`, it won't change until I save my report, it will then format itself in my mask and display my number as `1,3,3,7`.

I believe you are trying to restrict your user from giving an input other than in your format, (an input mask), I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770342/applying-a-phone-number-format-mask-in-oracle-apex) could help you achieve what you are trying .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's very helpful thank you!