# Applying a format mask in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

How do you define a format mask in Oracle APEX for social security numbers and phone numbers like "XXX-XXX-XXXX"?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770342/applying-a-phone-number-format-mask-in-oracle-apex

Comment: You could also consider redaction https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/data-redaction-12cr1, or the humble translate function https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690

Comment: Thanks  Littlefoot, but can you provide me the steps to do that   ,  i tried that but  this error appeared    =>   $(...).inputmask is not a function

Comment: Jaw, where are you trying to use the format mask, in JavaScript? What is this for, an item, a column in a report? If either of those, just check the item settings.

Comment: Thanks dan ,working fine now.